# Quarkus SmallRye Kafka Connector vs. Kafka Bare APIs

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, quarkus, smallrye

We are in the process of writing a lightweight Kafka microservice that will be responsible for managing the complexities around Kafka integration for an Event-driven Architecture. Other applications will only communicate with this Kafka-microservice over HTTP.

Q1: When comparing the [Quarkus SmallRye Kafka Connector](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/2/kafka/kafka.html#kafka-installation) and the [Kafka Bare APIs](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/allclasses-noframe.html), it seems like Quarkus/Smallrye gives clean annotation-based config to get up and running quickly, but we were wondering if it is production-ready, and if it has built-in flexibility to configure Kafka interactions at very granular-level if needed (through `mp.messaging.*`)?

Q2: Are there any gotchas around going with the SmallRye Kafka Connector?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Q1: The Kafka connector is definitely production-ready. See https://quarkus.io/blog/decathlon-user-story/ as reference.

Q2: The Kafka connector wraps the Apache Kafka client and handles asynchronous processing correctly. However, it wraps the "bare" kafka client. There are a few limitations. For example, it does not handle Kafka transaction at the moment.